# Unmarshalling XML JAXB with multiple elements same name

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall an XML document that has multiple elements with the same name. I am not sure whether I need to create an Arraylist of my bean and pass it to the unmarshaller. I am hoping that somebody would give me some pointers to figure this out. The XML that I am trying to parse comes as a SOAP response but I stripped out the envelope so I only have teh body of it, it looks like this:

```
<return>
    <row>
        <fkdevice>bddc228e-4774-18b3-9c64-e218cbef7a8x</fkdevice>
    </row>
    <row>
        <fkdevice>74a5a260-bbd9-0491-7c58-0b1983180d2c</fkdevice>
    </row>
    <row>
        <fkdevice>312b5326-d7f1-4fb6-b1d9-dd96bb016152</fkdevice>
    </row>
    <row>
        <fkdevice>ed110481-e1e1-4659-ae09-1d23d888292b</fkdevice>
    </row>
</return>
```

This is returned from a table that has more than 50 fields, but I created a testBean and I defined fkdevice only just to make it simple my bean looks like this:

```
package beans;
//imports    

@XmlRootElement(name="return")
public class testBean {
   //I think I need an arraylist here because I have multiple elements with teh same name.
   public ArrayList<string> fkdevice;

   public ArrayList<String> getFkdevice(){
       return fkdevice;
   }

   public void setFkdevice(ArrayList<String> fkdevice){
       this.fkdevice = fkdevice;
   }
}
```

This gives me an error: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has two properties of the same name "fkdevice" and it points to the getter and setter.

Any info could be helpful, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="return")
public class returnBean {
   private ArrayList<Row> rows;

   public ArrayList<Row> getRows(){
       return rows;
   }

   public void setRows(ArrayList<Row> rows){
       this.rows = rows;
   }
}
```

Notice the field is private now.

And then you probably don't need annotation here:

```
public class Row {
    private String fkdevice;

    public String getFkdevice() {
        return fkdevice;
    }

    public void setFkdevice(String val) {
        fkdevice = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I had a "name" or some other fields similar to fkdevice, this works but I cant get to them. So if I print x.getRow().get(0) this prints [row:null] when I debug I can see that row has children fkdevice as firstchild and name as nextsibling but I cant figure out how to get to them?

Comment: Where is the `<name>` in the XML? Same level as the `<fkdevice>` inside the `<row>` ?

Comment: It just occured to me that 'rows' is a much better name for the list. With the change you say `x.getRows().get(0)` which is intelligible.

Comment: yeah makes more sense, how can I get to the other fields if I have something like this:
<row>
    <fkdevice>dskjhdjshds</fkdevice>
    <name>dsdsds</name>
</row>

Comment: Add more properties, getters and setters to the `Row` class.

Comment: I did, I added getters and setters for every field I have in teh database but what I get returned is an ArrayList of Rows. and I cant get to whats beneath a "row"

Comment: `x.getRows().get(0).getFkdevice()` and `x.getRows().get(0).getName()` and so forth.

Comment: I changed the declaration of the ArrayList in returnBean to ArrayList<DeviceNumPlanMap>, I have replaced the Row class with DeviceNumPlanMap class that contains all fields. Then I call the unrmarshaller by doing DeviceNumPlanMap x = (DeviceNumPlanMap) util.convertToObject(xmlString, returnBean.class); and then this fails when I do (in my unmarshaller) "return (Object) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); The error I get is "String index out of range: 1" there is no way to debug this because its coming from teh unmarshaller

Comment: You can add logging to each setter function and each class's default constructor (which you may have to add) and at least trace how far jaxb got before the error occurred. You can also wrap the reader in a logging reader that shows how much of the XML string got read. That's a little more work.

Comment: it read the xml string fine and all of it, and it fails when invoking the unmarshal method, stepping into this does not help. I am trying to add a logger to each setter and see what is happening. Does the unmarshaller has a limit on how big the xml String is ??

Comment: If I pass DeviceNumPlanMap to the unmarshaller instead of returnBean it does not complain but it gets the value as null

Comment: You could try it with stripped down xml containing only a single `<row>` and pass the DeviceNumPlanMap to the unmarshaller. (This isn't a java `Map` by any chance is it? Its just a POJO with the work Map in its name? Right?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to by : ""This isn't a java Map by any chance is it? Its just a POJO with the work Map in its name. It works with a a single element in each row, butr with multiple element in each row thats when it fails

Comment: DeviceNumPlanMap is just a POJO similar to the Row class you wrote aboce, except it is named after teh table that I am referring to and it has about 30 fields

Comment: I can't believe I have been banging my head against this since 9 am. I found the problem, since I have about 30 fields I missed one and although I have a ValidationEventHandler implemented it still complained. So I just added that missing field and it worked like charm. Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

Your field and method are both public. By default, JAXB binds every public field and every getter/setter pair.

One solution is to use `@XmlAccessorType` to specify that fields and only fields are bound to XML.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="return")
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class testBean {

    @XmlElement( name="fkdevice" )
    public ArrayList<string> fkdevice;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I usually annotate each field with at least @ XmlElement or @ XmlTransient. Added annotation above.